# Grafana's alert notification templating does not seem to work

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating, grafana-alerts

I've tried following the steps in [this link](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/add-notification-template/), but what I see in the alert message is the text itself, i.e. `${Label}`, rather than the value of that label. I do not use template variables.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So I believe the answer here is that your not running version 7.4 of grafana. This resolved it in my case.

Comment: I'm using grafana v8.0.6 but still facing this issue.. Are there anything else that I'm missing?

Comment: Still not working on v8.2.5

Comment: Same problem here. I guess maybe ${Label} was just a syntax example and we should be using a different term.